# Is there a way to select everything right of first string in line

Tags: ms-word, wildcard

So I got a body of space separated text and I'm trying to mine names. These names are the first :

```
Tsuru   Stork greeting for a long last life.    Unisex
Yama    Mountain; Restrainer;   Unisex      
Yuka    A bright Star   Unisex      
Yumi    A beautiful archery bow Unisex      
Yuna    The archer  Unisex
```

How can I select everything right of the first string in each row?

I figured out how to select the names themselves with this:

```
(\n+)[A-Z]{1}\w+
```

But there doesn't seem to be an easy way in word to highlight, copy then paste the selection.

In summary, how do I select elements after the first string in a new line?

Comment: Please show an example of what should match in your input (*select elements after the first string in a new line* is not clear)

Comment: By *"there doesn't seem to be an easy way in word"*, did you mean you working in Microsoft Word?

Comment: If you just want to match the first word in each line use ```^\w+```. Make sure you use the global(g) and multiline(m) regex flags. [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/Nnn3ei/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is done in Microsoft Word then try the following:

```
 *^13
```

This stands for:

- - A space character.
- `*` - Match any sequence of characters.
- `^13` - Match a newline character (ASCII 13).

If I understood your question correctly, this will highlight all text to the right of the first *word* in each line. See the below screenshot (don't mind the Dutch pls.):

[image]

If you actually need to make sure you select everything after the first *multiple space* seperation, then maybe use  `{3,4}*^13`:

[image]

Again, don't mind the Dutch along with the locale parameter delimiter (semi-colon) in the occurence indicator. This will be a comma if your locale is English.

Comment: Dude, you're amazing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex like : `(^\w+)`

`^` start of line
`\w+` matches world char one or many times

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sPTodd/1)